# Is there a way to force duplicity to use IPv4 instead of IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, python, duplicity

In the below command, `example.com` has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses but SSH server listens only on the IPv4 address.

Is there a way to request duplicity to use IPv4 only?

```
duplicity --progress --ssh-options -oIdentityFile=./cloud.pem --encrypt-key=REDACTED --full-if-older-than 2W --include-filelist ./list.txt --exclude '**' --exclude /root/.cache/duplicity / sftp://example.com//mnt/duplicity/
```

Comment: What is the point? Why publish an address and then decide not to use it? Either its usable, then the client *should chose freely*, because the client preference is usually ideal. Or its not working, then it should not even be there, regardless of client configuration.

Comment: probably a routerbox nat'ing some IPv4 port. surely resolving IPv4 to a different domain name would be cleaner, but maybe that is not wanted/possible?

Answer (score 2):

SSH defaults to `AddressFamily=any` - switch it to `AddressFamily=inet` (IPv4) or `AddressFamily=inet6` (IPv6) when you want only one IP version attempted. You may need to put such ssh options in `~/.ssh/config`, even though you already have `-oIdentityFile=` in your cmdline. At least my manual page still tells me:

> If needed provide more host specific options via ssh_config file.

It would look something like this:

```
# cat ~/.ssh/config
Host example.com
  AddressFamily=inet
  IdentityFile=/path/to/certificate.pem
```

Verify your configuration is picked up by reviewing the *effective* configuration for that host:

```
ssh -G example.com | grep -i address
addressfamily inet
```

Mind warnings potentially emitted on duplicity startup, as I have seen its non-OpenSSH backend silently mistreat ssh options before.

Comment: It seems dupllicity ignore those arguments: both as a CLI and as ~/.ssh/config

Comment: @Halacs It works for me, my destination is `rsync://` though... Did you confirm your configuration works by manually calling `sftp -vv example.com` ? If that works, but duplicity does not, maybe it is because are not using OpenSSH, but a broken version of paramiko, which can silently pretend to be a drop-on-replacement even when it should know it is not. You can force duplicity revert to the legacy "just use the sftp binary" behaviour by specifying the destination with `pexpect+sftp://`.

Comment: another option would be using `pexpect+sftp://` and adding `--ssh-options='AddressFamily=inet'` as a temporary overwrite of the `sftp` command call parameter.

Comment: I checked `pxexpect+sftp://` and `sftp://` both with `--ssh-options` and with `~/.ssh/config` with no luck. To make sure, I checked with `ssh -G example.com | grep -i address` and it looks okay. Good news is, however, that `rsync://` with `--ssh-options='-oAddressFamily=inet'` argument works as expected so my problem is solved now. Thanks for all of you!

Comment: @Halacs Happy that you solved your immediate problem, but it got intriguing.. mind sharing your versions of OpenSSH, duplicity, python3-paramiko, ..? I wonder how rsync via ssh could possibly end up behaving different from sftp via ssh..

Comment: @anx sure!
duplicity/jammy,now 0.8.21-1build1 amd64; 
python3-paramiko/jammy,now 2.9.3-0ubuntu1 all; 
openssh-client/jammy-updates,now 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1 amd64; 
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: I tried and could not reproduce it on a matching Ubuntu jammy system. My remaining theories are inadvertent reuse of already-established connections  (`ControlMaster`) or hostname canonicalization changing what configuration is applied, which should also be visible when using `-G` on the ssh cmdline mentioned in `duplicity --verbosity debug` output.

Answer (score 0):

while [the answer above](https://serverfault.com/a/1134818/493381) sounds like a perfectly good solution i just want to add this.

> There is no global Python switch for this, ...
>
> Another would be to use an underlying way to get your C library to
> prefer IPv4 or disable IPv6. This will vary by platform, but on Linux
> using glibc you could edit /etc/gai.conf to always prefer IPv4 over
> IPv6:
>
> ```
> precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
> ```

as described on https://serverfault.com/a/1134818/493381